# "Debouncing" duplicate logs across distributed tasks

Tags: logging, architecture, unique, monitoring, debouncing

I'm currently building in a feeature to "debounce" duplicate logs, i.e. I want only one instance of a log to be recorded per "debounce period". Uniqueness will be determined per log by a variety of params (these would depend on the context of the log), what are some techniques people have used to achieve this? Keeping the question general because I'm curious about this across different types of systems.

The end state I care about is reducing noise when the team is reading through logs, so solutions at any stage (including deduplication after write) are on the table(.

I'm still thinking through a few different approaches, the question is open-ended. As it stands my most likely approach is scheduled & manual deduplication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.